# Button's click in listiview not working properly

Tags: android, listview, android-button, baseadapter

In my listview i set two buttons and one edittext but it is not working properly,the view of my buttons and edittext in listview is look like this

Button1 Edittext Button2

in my edittext i set 1,and Button1 is for decrement or minus and Button2 for increment or plus,but the issue is in every listitem it is not working properly,if i have three items in my listview,and if i increment in first item the operation is performing in third item,,

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_addtocart, container, false);

        totvalues=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.totaldisp);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        edtcopupon=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_coupon);
        btn_applycoupon=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.aplycoupoon);

        btn_applycoupon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_addtocart);
        plcordr=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.plcordr);
        plcordr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Placeorder tf = new Placeorder();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                tf.setArguments(bundle);
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.container_body, tf);
                ft.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

        ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactListItems>();
        contactList.clear();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM PHONE_CONTACTS ";
        Cursor c1 = SqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null & c1.getCount() != 0) {
            if (c1.moveToNext()) {
                do {
                    contactListItems = new ContactListItems();
                   contactListItems.setSlno(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("slno")));
                    contactListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("name")));
                    contactListItems.setPhone(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("phone")));
                    contactListItems.setSizes(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("sizes")));
                    contactListItems.setQtys(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("qtys")));
                    contactList.add(contactListItems);
                } while (c1.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        c1.close();

        contactListAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(getActivity(), contactList);
        list.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }



    public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        ViewHolder holder;
        ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList;
        String dollars = "\u0024";

        public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactListItems> list) {

            this.context = context;
            contactList = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return contactList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return contactList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_addtocart, null);
                holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propicaccept);

                holder.tvSlNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_size);
                holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proprice_addtocart);
                holder.tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proname_addtocart);
                holder.tvsizes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sizes);
                holder._decrease = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minuss_addtocart);
                holder.mBTIncrement = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus_addtocart);
                holder._value = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_procount_addtocart);

                holder.mBTIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //increment();
                        int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder._value.getText().toString());
                        mValue++;
                        quntity++;
                        tots = pric * quntity;
                        System.out.println("INCRESE VALUES" + tots);
                        totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));
                        holder._value.setText("" + mValue);
                    }
                });

                holder._decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        //decrement();

                        int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder._value.getText().toString());
                        mValue--;
                        quntity--;
                        tots = pric * quntity;
                        System.out.println("INCRESE VALUES" + tots);
                        totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));
                        if (mValue < 0) {
                            System.out.println("not valid");
                            holder._decrease.setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            holder._value.setText("" + mValue);
                        }
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.tvName.setText(dollars+contactListItems.getName());
            holder.tvPhone.setText(contactListItems.getPhone());
            holder.tvsizes.setText(contactListItems.getSizes());
            holder._value.setText(contactListItems.getQtys());

            quntity=Float.parseFloat(contactListItems.getQtys());

            pric=Float.parseFloat(contactListItems.getName());

            tots=pric*quntity;

            totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));

            System.out.println("QTYSSS>>" + quntity);
            System.out.println("PRICCC>>" + pric);
            // float aditya=+tots;
            System.out.println("TOTTTT>>" + tots);




            //aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{
            ImageView propic;
            TextView tvSlNo;
            TextView tvName;
            TextView tvPhone;
            Button mBTIncrement;
            TextView tvsizes;
            Button _decrease;
            public EditText _value;
        }

    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rectback"

    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_addtocart"
        android:src="@drawable/productfirst"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relfirsrt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_addtocart"

        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/proname_addtocart"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:maxLength="13"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"


            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt_size"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt_sizes"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img_addtocart"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_addtocart"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_addtocart"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:id="@+id/minuss_addtocart"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/minusbox"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edt_procount_addtocart"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/edt_procount_addtocart" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:id="@+id/edt_procount_addtocart"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/inputbox"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/plus_addtocart"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/plus_addtocart" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:id="@+id/plus_addtocart"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:background="@drawable/addbox"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:focusable="true"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/proprice_addtocart"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also share list_item_addtocart.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `onClick` listener and tag assigning code outside the if-else block.

```
 if (convertView == null) {

}
else {
}

holder.position = position;

  holder.mBTIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //increment();
                            int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder._value.getText().toString());
                            mValue++;
                            quntity++;
                            tots = pric * quntity;
                            System.out.println("INCRESE VALUES" + tots);
                            totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));
                            holder._value.setText("" + mValue);
                        }
                    });

                    holder._decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            //decrement();

                            int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder._value.getText().toString());
                            mValue--;
                            quntity--;
                            tots = pric * quntity;
                            System.out.println("INCRESE VALUES" + tots);
                            totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));
                            if (mValue < 0) {
                                System.out.println("not valid");
                                holder._decrease.setEnabled(false);
                            } else {
                                holder._value.setText("" + mValue);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: can not resolve position...and do i need to remove this line holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();..from else part?

Comment: I can't understand why position variable cannot be resolved at your side and `holder.position purpose`. Well actually essence of whole code is that holder should be carrying correct instances of buttons and edittext for a particular row. Moreover, in OnClick listeners, you should be able to access correct EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base your logic on the position of the click, because the adapter may refresh itself after the click and change the position;

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ViewHolder holder;
ArrayList<ContactListItems> contactList;
ArrayList<Integer> values;
String dollars = "\u0024";

public ContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactListItems> list) {

    this.context = context;
    contactList = list;
    values = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        values.add(contactListItems.getQtys());
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_addtocart, null);
        holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propicaccept);

        holder.tvSlNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_size);
        holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proprice_addtocart);
        holder.tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proname_addtocart);
        holder.tvsizes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sizes);
        holder._decrease = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.minuss_addtocart);
        holder.mBTIncrement = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus_addtocart);
        holder._value = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_procount_addtocart);

        holder.mBTIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = holder.position;
                int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder._value.getText().toString());
                mValue++;
                quntity++;
                tots = pric * quntity;
                System.out.println("INCRESE VALUES" + tots);
                totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));
                values.set(position, mValue);
            }
        });

        holder._decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = holder.position;
                int mValue = Integer.parseInt(holder._value.getText().toString());
                mValue--;
                quntity--;
                tots = pric * quntity;
                System.out.println("INCRESE VALUES" + tots);
                totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));
                values.set(position, mValue);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.position = position;
    holder.tvName.setText(dollars+contactListItems.getName());
    holder.tvPhone.setText(contactListItems.getPhone());
    holder.tvsizes.setText(contactListItems.getSizes());

    int value = values.get(position);
    if (value < 0) {
        holder._decrease.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        holder._value.setText("" + mValue);
    }
    quntity=Float.parseFloat(contactListItems.getQtys());

    pric=Float.parseFloat(contactListItems.getName());

    tots=pric*quntity;

    totvalues.setText(String.valueOf(tots));

    System.out.println("QTYSSS>>" + quntity);
    System.out.println("PRICCC>>" + pric);
    // float aditya=+tots;
    System.out.println("TOTTTT>>" + tots);




    //aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    return convertView;
}

 class ViewHolder{
        int position;
        ImageView propic;
        TextView tvSlNo;
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvPhone;
        Button mBTIncrement;
        TextView tvsizes;
        Button _decrease;
        public EditText _value;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is holder.position here?

Comment: i dont understand what changes you did?

Comment: if you add array of integers with values, you can pull the right value after the click from this array just by that you update the array with the new value. this way you keep the data updated every call to getView()

Comment: my all the values set as 0,,and click event not working

Comment: values.add(contactListItems.getQtys()); here its shows red line..and bro i am getting edttext value from database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87742/discussion-between-yshahak-and-lakhan).

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing adapter like below

```
private Context context;
private List<ContactListItems> items;

/**
 * @param context
 * @param groupList
 */
public TestListAdapter(Context context, List<ContactListItems> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.li_plus_minus, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.plus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        holder.minus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        holder.et = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ContactListItems item = items.get(position);
    holder.et.setText(String.valueOf(item.value));
    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(item));
    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(item));
    return convertView;
}

class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ContactListItems item;

    public ClickListener(ContactListItems item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.minus) {
            item.value--;
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.plus) {
            item.value++;
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    Button plus, minus;
    EditText et;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your Customise view parent layout.

```
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: In your R.layout.li_plus_minus  And put that setonclick listener code for both button outsize if-else statement . then it work . let me know ..

Comment: In your customized layout parant layout And put that setonclick listener code for both button outside if-else statement . then it work . let me know if it doesnt work

Comment: where can i set this property?